# Redirect user to page with specific URL based on his/her username

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I want to redirect a page to another page based on user's username. For Example, If I have a page with URL something like "sitename/store" and when user open that page, it should redirect to page with URL like "sitename/store/username". In this scenario, username is variable. Is there any code which is available in functions.php? or is there any way to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: @Sonal Khunt Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
 <?php
  header("Location: sitename/store/". $usernameVariable);
  ?>
```